# Looking around with Accelerometer - Unity3D C#

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

So I'm making an FPS Android game and I'm trying to make it possible to look around using the accelerometer. I've attached a script to the player that has the MainCamera attached to it, and here's the void that I put the code in.

```
void lookAround1()
{
    float accelx, accely, accelz = 0;
    accelx = Input.acceleration.x;
    accely = Input.acceleration.y;
    accelz = Input.acceleration.z;
    transform.Rotate(accely * Time.deltaTime * 10f, accelx * Time.deltaTime * 10f, accelz*Time.deltaTime * 10f);
}
```

When I run the game, the player GameObject just keeps spinning around on its own and it's impossible to control it with the accelerometer. Any way to fix this?

Here's what the game looks like to give a better idea:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this: https://gist.github.com/chanibal/baf46307c4fee3c699d5 - drag it to your main camera.

There is some debug (remove `OnGUI()` to mute it) and you'll likely want to remove reseting the angle when touching the screen (remove `Input.touchCount > 0 ||`).